# type casting a String to Object[][]

Tags: java, arrays, string, casting

I would like to convert below String to simple two dimensional array (Object[][]).

```
String personArray ="{{Melroy,25,India},{Jack,26,USA}}"; // nothing but a simple string with appearance of a 2D array
```

1. Can this be done in the first place?
2. If so what is the simplest way?

Any help any inputs will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That string doesn't even appear to be valid

Comment: you cant cast it, you have to parse it

Comment: @Andrey it is not duplicate, as string is not in JSON format

Comment: @user902383 sorry my bad. But then this question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: did u test it on an IDE like eclipse?

Comment: Could be done with some regular expressions and some splitting.

Comment: @user902383 Getting there with a String ?

Comment: Dude, the code you supplied doesn't even compile. How can you expect effort from us when you bring us this?

Comment: guys sorry about the sting in the question. It really is more like this String personArray ="{{Melroy,25,India},{Jack,26,USA}}"; its an unusal situation in java, but this String is being fetched from the database

Comment: _"but this String is being fetched from the database"_ Are you sure, this is the correct format? Have you actually printed out the exact value retrieved?

Comment: yes I have. The problem is that in the database, i am returning a refcursor which returns some primitive values, an an array . The array further contains primitive values and an array(cast to character varying). this casted array is being returned to the java end in the mentioned format(printed and seen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from beginning, identify format of your data structure,

seems like your inner array have format `{String, Number, String}`, to find it, we will create simple regular expression `\\{([A-Za-z]+),([0-9]+),([A-Za-z]+)\\}`

to make it work properly, you might need to add few modifications, but bellow code will work for your small case

```
    String personArray ="{{Melroy,25,India},{Jack,26,USA}}";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{([A-Za-z]+),([0-9]+),([A-Za-z]+)\\}"); 

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(personArray);

    List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
     //using list as we don't know number of final elements, 

    int start = 0;
    while(
        matcher.find(start)){
        list.add(new Object[]{matcher.group(1),matcher.group(2),matcher.group(3)});
        start  = matcher.end();

    }

    //convert to array, to have required format
    Object[][] array = list.toArray(new Object[0][]);

    //test result
    for (Object[] arr : array)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot . the solution worked perfectly, Altough i guess I might  need to reconsider my approach of returning the kind of structure I need from DB.